# How do I add API endpoints to an existing Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im adding an API to my app built with Rails 4. I've googled a few things and this is what I've come up with.

in my routes.rb

```
 My normal html view endpoints up here
 ...........
 ...........

 # API
 require 'api_constraints'

 namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, path: nil, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do
   scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
     resources :users, only: :show
   end
 end
```

My api_constraints.rb

```
class ApiConstraints
 def initialize(options)
   @version = options[:version]
   @default = options[:default]
 end

 def matches?(req)
   @default || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.MYAPP.v#{@version}")
 end
end
```

my bas api controller `(controllers/api_controller.rb)`

```
class Api::V1::ApiController < ApplicationController
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

end
```

my api users_controller `(controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb)`

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::ApiController
 respond_to :json

 def show
   respond_with User.find(params[:id])
 end
end
```

The problem I'm having is that when I visit `api.MYAPP.com/users/USERID` it is just directing to the normal users_controller.rb showing me the html view, when it should be routing to the api/v1/users_controller.rb.

When I run rake routes I get

`user GET    /users/:id(.:format)    users#show`

and

`api_user GET    /users/:id(.:format)    api/v1/users#show {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}`

If I change my api namespace to have the version in the url like so

```
 namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, path: nil, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' } do
   namespace :v1 do
     resources :users, only: :show
   end
 end
```

It of course works fine when I visit `api.myapp.com/v1/users/USERID`

What am I doing wrong here?